# Detect console end of the input in PHP-Cli

Tags: php

Is there any form to detect the end of a console input?

Im using something like this:

```
<?php
while($consoleInput = fgets(STDIN)) {

 //do something

}
?>
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you feel your question has been sufficiently answered, please click on the checkmark to accept it.  Also vote up all answers you found useful in any way.

Answer (score 1):

How about [`feof()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php)?  Untested, but I believe this will work.

```
while (!feof(STDIN)) {
  $consoleInput = fgets(STDIN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (feof(STDIN)) {
   do_something()
};
```